# Is it possible to configure synonym to [retag]?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is it possible to "synonymize" [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga), [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime), [visual-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-novel), [light-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel) to [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag)?

I'm thinking that it might help new comers who don't have enough reputation more options to arrive at a dummy tag, instead of giving up posting the question because the tag for the series they want to ask is not available.

Comment: Manga and Anime are actually blacklisted tags, FYI.

Comment: Visual-novel and Light-novel should probably be blacklisted too, if not for anything else, at least for consistency.

Comment: Shog's suggestions [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/1141/49) are also relevant

Comment: @JNat: The point is that, since they are blacklisted tags (or should be blacklisted), they can be used as another way to select [retag].

Comment: As Shog pointed out, it's better to, instead, improve the message that gets displayed. Prompting users to select [retag] (even though, I assume, the guidance would mention that it should only be used when there isn't an available tag for them to use and they can't create a new one) will leave us with a lot more of question with [retag] instead of the few edge cases that would definitely need it, simply because it's the path with the least resistance for a new user who just wants to get their question posted and get answers to it.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you're trying to solve should be handled a bit differently. If a user doesn't know what to type into tags list, they *may* type "anime" or "manga" and then a popup would appear explaining how to use tags if one of those blacklisted words is detected.

Currently it's this:

[image]

That message is not very helpful at all.

To make it more user-friendly, some solutions would have to be added, like "Add the name of the anime/manga you're asking about". The message itself has to be enough for a new user to know what to do, without resorting to links to relevant meta posts, which are very long and you know it's not a nice solution. But we could think of a good way to solve this.

Comment: Not including any tag should default to adding the retag by the system.

Comment: Sometimes people forget to add tags. I guess when the "You gotta add tags" notification shows up, it could also contain help for finding appropriate tags, with "retag" as a last resort, and I'd say it should not be immediately visible, so lazy users would not go straight for it.

Comment: @Gao: I think that's a good idea.

Comment: @Gao You _can't_ not include any tags.

Comment: I agree with @Hakase in that [tag:retag] should _definitely_ not be immediately suggested, as we'll just end up with a ton of questions from new users with that tag and a lot of work on our hands.

Comment: @JNat That's the problem: you *can't* not include any tag. We either end up with a ton of questions with the retag or a ton of questions that are inappropriately tagged. The amount of work on our hands doesn't change either way. A warning message should be shown first if posting a question without selecting any tag, but should the user choose to ignore the warning and click the post question button the second time, they should be allowed to do so.

Comment: @Gao And then have a front page be filled with untagged questions? What's the benefit of that?

Comment: Like I told y'all [a year ago](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/having-identification-request-and-retag-show-up-as-tag-suggestions-by-defaul/1141#1141), we can change the error shown for the anime tag. Since you haven't done that yet, arguing for some crazy, complicated alternate solution is just a waste of your time, @Gao.